# Haskero: The following GHC options are incompatible with GHCi and have not been passed to it: -threaded

Tags: visual-studio-code, haskell-stack

I've Haskero plugin extension installed for VS Code.
When I start my VS code editor, I get the below error message.

```
    stderr:
    The following GHC options are incompatible with GHCi and have not been passed to it: -threaded
    Configuring GHCi with the following packages: continue-example
    <command line>: cannot satisfy -package Decimal
        (use -v for more information)


    Code: -32603
```

Below are the dependencies for I configured in `package.yaml`

```
    dependencies:
    - base
    - stm
    - Decimal
    - async
    - random
```

ghc version configured in `stack.yaml` is `resolver: ghc-8.2.2`.

Looks like there is some issue with the Decimal package. 
I'm new to Haskell. Any idea why I get this error?